# How to make cordova, Java SDK and Android SDK work together?

Tags: android, cordova, java-8

I can't configure recent versions (August 2020) of cordova and Android SDK to work.

## I have JDK installed.

Version: 1.8.0_261

The `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Java`.

`C:\Java\bin` added to `PATH`.

## I have Android Studio installed.

Version: `4.0.1`

The platform is `Android 6.0.0`

The following are added to `PATH`:

`C:\Android\sdk\tools`

`C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

`C:\Android\sdk\tools\bin`

Environment variables `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and deprecated `ANDROID_HOME` are set to `C:\Android\sdk\tools\bin`.

## I have Cordova installed.

Version: `10.0.0`

`cordova platform ls`:

```
6.0.0
Installed platforms:
  android 6.4.0
  browser
Available platforms:
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0
```

## The problem

At the moment I get the following:

on `cordova requirements`:

> Requirements check results for android: Cannot read property 'version'
> of null

on `cordova build android`

> Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it
> manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update
> your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Before these I also tried installing both cordova-android 9 and Android 9 SDK and had the same message, except `ANDROID_HOME` was `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

> Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it
> manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update
> your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to do was to restart the pc. (facepalm)

Comment: You probably just had to restart your command prompt / terminal windows, in order for environment variable changes to take effect.